# Sharing Small MongoDB Dataset on GitHub for Collaborative Team

Tags: database, mongodb, git, github, mongodb-query

I'm part of a small team working with MongoDB and we're looking for the best way to share our MongoDB data on GitHub. Our team size is small, and the dataset isn't too large. We want to ensure that we're following best practices for version control and collaboration while keeping the process streamlined. What are the recommended steps and tools to effectively share MongoDB data on GitHub for a team of our size? We'd like to maintain data integrity and make collaboration as smooth as possible.

**Details:**

- Our team size consists of only a few members, so we don't need complex enterprise-level solutions.
- The MongoDB dataset we're working with is relatively small, making it manageable for sharing.
- We want to maintain proper version control for our data to track changes and easily collaborate.
- Data integrity is important to us, so any method we use should ensure that the shared data remains consistent.
- We're open to using scripts, utilities, or existing tools that can help automate the process and reduce human error.

**Specifically, we're looking for advice on:**

1. How to export MongoDB data in a way that's suitable for sharing on GitHub.
2. Recommended tools or libraries to automate the export and versioning process.
3. Efficient methods to keep the shared data consistent and avoid conflicts.
4. Best practices for setting up a GitHub repository to house the MongoDB data.
5. Any tips for documentation to accompany the shared data so that other team members can understand its structure and purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run MongoDB server on GitHub. But you can use free [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/database)

On the database you can frequently run `mongoexport` or `mongodump` (see [MongoDB Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/))

`mongoexport` creates JSON files which are clear text, whereas `mongodump` creates a binary file. These files you could upload to Github, however versioning would be difficult on binary files.